# I/O timeout while trying to login Heroku in Unix system?

Tags: node.js, unix, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-api

All dependencies and Plug-ins are installed correctly but but while I am trying to login via heroku login command and give credentials  it gives me following error.

> Post https://api.heroku.com/login: dial tcp: lookup api.heroku.com on
>   127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:51660->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout

If someone faced same issue please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue on macOS 12.1. Need Help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything above and nothing worked. What got it working for me (Ubuntu 14.04) was adding this line to my `/etc/hosts`:

```
23.21.149.112 api.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same kind of error with another application, in Ubuntu 17.10. The problem seemed to come from a wrongly configured `/etc/resolv.conf`. NetworkManager was managing this file, while it should have been left to `systemd-resolved`. The solution in my case was to replace `/etc/resolv.conf` by a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

I found that out by comparing my config (upgraded from 17.04, possibly with some bugs) to a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, where `/etc/resolv.conf` was a symlink.